# Iterate through files with os.path.join and read each file

Tags: python, for-loop, os.walk

I'm new to Python and encountering a roadblock I can't get past. I'm wanting to iterate through a set of XML files that are organized in subdirectories, open each file, and read its contents.

This code works to iterate through the subdirectories:

```
record_count = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/testing/'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xml'):
            record_count = record_count + 1
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            print(record_count, path)
```

It returns what I would expect - the `path` variable is correctly updated with each iteration:

```
1 /testing/subfolder/mufs190-1951-dpl2k4-i001.reference_export.xml
2 /testing/subfolder/mufs190-1951-dpl2k3-i001.reference_export.xml
```

Next I added the code at the bottom to read each XML file and return some information from it:

```
record_count = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/testing/'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xml'):
            record_count = record_count + 1
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            print(record_count, path)

            with open(path, 'r') as f:
                tree = ET.parse(f)
                root = tree.getroot()
                # Retrieve the item's title
                for citeinfo in root.findall('./idinfo/citation/citeinfo'):
                    title = citeinfo.find('title').text
                print(title)
```

The code successfully works on the first iteration, and then throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/testing/subfolder.py", line 25, in <module>
    path = os.path.join(root, file)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/posixpath.py", line 76, in join
    a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Element
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're reusing the variable `root` for `tree.getroot()`. Use a different variable name there.

Comment: You are overwriting root here: root = tree.getroot().  Choose a different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're inadvertently overwriting one of your variables; specifically, your loop starts with

```py
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/testing/'):
```

but then inside your `with open` block, you invoke

```py
                root = tree.getroot()
```

Which turns `root` from the `str` expected by `os.path.join` into an `Element` which it does not know how to handle.

Comment: Yep, sure enough that fixed it. Much appreciation for catching that mistake!